# sort columns in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 2 columns of data imported from using textscan.  The data looks like this where **U** is **undetect** and **D** is **detect**

```
mydata=

.51 U
.57 D
.48 U
.47 D

 my data = [4x1 double]    [4x1 char]
```

I want to sort the data by the first column and so the data would look like this

```
.47  D
.48  U
.51  U    
.57  D
```

I would like to preserve the cell structure so that the following command to assign logical value still hold true:

```
c = zeros(size(mydata,1),1); % preallocate empty matrix 

c = mydata{2} == 'U';
for i = 1:size(mydata,1)
      curValue = mydata{i,2};
      data{i,3} =  ~isempty(curValue) && ischar(curValue) && strcmp(curValue ,'U');
end
```

I read about sortrows but the function is used to sort matrix containing just numbers.

Does anyone have a solution for sorting arrays with a mixture of numbers and characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html) by one vector and apply the sorting index to another vector.

```
[mydata{1},idx] = sort(mydata{1});
mydata{2} =  mydata{2}(idx);
```

Comment: Oh, that's nicer than mine. :) You can make it even simper by replacing `cell2mat(mydata(:,1)` by `mydata{1}`.

Comment: @3lectrologos: Found my error and corrected before I saw your answer and comment. I somehow missed the existing data structure in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can directly sort the cell array, because each cell is considered a different "entity". You can always sort the numbers, use the indices to sort the characters, and then put it back in the cell array:

```
nums = mydata{1};
chars = mydata{2};
[~, ind] = sort(nums);
sortednums = nums(ind);
sortedchars = chars(ind);
mydata{1} = sortednums;
mydata{2} = sortedchars;
```