# Sort the first sorted column that have the same number based on the second column in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a set of data and ask Matlab to sort in ascending order like this

```
filename=input('Type filename.txt: ','s');
fid=fopen(filename);
mydata=textscan(fid,'%f %c','headerlines', 1, 'delimiter','\t');
fclose(fid);

% sort data
[mydata{1},idx] = sort(mydata{1})
mydata{2} =  mydata{2}(idx)
```

Data came out like this:

```
0.41    U
0.41    U
0.41    U
0.41    D
0.41    U
0.41    D
0.41    U
0.41    U
0.41    D
0.41    U
0.42    U
0.42    D
0.42    U
0.42    U
0.42    U
0.42    D
0.43    U
```

U = undetect and D = Detects. If you notice carefully, if the first column has the same number, say 0.41, Matlab would sort the first column and disregard the order of the second column.  What I would like Matlab to do is if it sees the same number in the first column, then place the number based on the second column, U first before D.
The final sorted data would like this:

```
0.41    U
0.41    U
0.41    U
0.41    U
0.41    U
0.41    U
0.41    U
0.41    D
0.41    D
0.41    D
0.42    U
0.42    U
0.42    U
0.42    U
0.42    D
0.42    D
0.43    U
```

If somehow it would make it easier, I can make 1=Detect and 0=Nondetect
Thank you for your help and time.

Edit:  I should also add that sortrow does not work because I would like to preserve the data structure so that the following code would follow

```
o=mydata{1} %index the first column of the array mydata


c = zeros(size(mydata,1),1); % preallocate empty matrix 
c = mydata{2} == 'U';
for i = 1:size(mydata,1)
 curValue = mydata{i,2};
 data{i,3} =  ~isempty(curValue) && ischar(curValue) && strcmp(curValue ,'U');
```

end

Comment: Please post your data as well, to understand the question better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620185/sort-columns-in-matlab

Comment: It is actually an extension of that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sortrows`, but you have to convert `mydata` into a n-by-2 cell array first:

```
mydata = [num2cell(mydata{1}),num2cell(mydata{2})];

cs = sortrows(mydata,[1,-2]) %# sort the first col ascending, then second descending
cs = 
    [0.41]    'U'
    [0.41]    'U'
    [0.41]    'U'
    [0.41]    'U'
    [0.41]    'U'
    [0.41]    'U'
    [0.41]    'U'
    [0.41]    'D'
    [0.41]    'D'
    [0.41]    'D'
    [0.42]    'U'
    [0.42]    'U'
    [0.42]    'U'
    [0.42]    'U'
    [0.42]    'D'
    [0.42]    'D'
    [0.43]    'U'
```

You can backtransform it by calling

```
mydataSorted = {cat(1,cs{:,1}),cat(1,cs{:,2})};
```

Obviously, if you transform your data so that `mydata{2}` is numeric, you can simply forego the cell array and call `sortrows` straight away.

Comment: Tried sortrows and got this error.   mydata = 

    [47x1 double]    [47x1 char]

??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> sortrows>sort_cell_back_to_front at 137
            ndx = ndx(ind);

Error in ==> sortrows at 90
        ndx = sort_cell_back_to_front(x_sub, col);

Comment: @TranHuynh: I added the line how I transformed `mydata` first to make `sortrows` work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a copy of MATLAB right now, so I can't verify the code, but I believe that MATLAB's sort algorithm is [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).  Because of that, if you sort on the second column, THEN sort on the first column, you should get what you want.

That is, all of the 'U's will be grouped together, and all of the 'D's will be grouped together, after the first sort (on the second column).  Then, even after the second sort (on the first column), the  U's and D's will remain grouped together for each numeric value group.